# How to check if tap happened in a specific place

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to check if a tap is happening in a specific region on the screen. I've set up a TapGestureRecognizer this is the code I have right now:

```
func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var point = tap.locationInView(self.view)
    println("tapped")

    if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.Region.frame, point)) {
            println("touch")
            var y = kbHeight - textYoutube.center.y
            youTextConst.constant += y
        }
    }
}
```

The app recognized the tap but not the tap in the specific region, What's wrong with the code?

*UPDATE*

I don't know if it matters but the Region is a TextView

Comment: Think about the different coordinate systems you're using here...

Comment: Before you can call CGRectContainsPoint you need a rect and a point _in the same coordinate system_. What I would do is convert `point` to the coordinate system of `self.Region` itself, and now compare `point` to `self.Region.bounds`. See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame and http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_bounds_and_center

Answer (score 13):

(**NOTE**: I am assuming that `self.Region` is a UIView. You do not explain what it is in your question, so I have to guess what it might be. By the way, please do not use a capital letter for the name of a property. I am doing this only to give you an easy match to your own code.)

Think about coordinate systems. You are saying

```
var point = tap.locationInView(self.view)
```

That means that `point` is in `self.view`'s coordinate system. But that's the wrong coordinate system if you're going to call CGRectContainsPoint. Before you can work out the relationship between `point` and `self.Region`, you need to get `point` into the same coordinate system as `self.Region`:

```
point = self.Region.convertPoint(point, fromView:self.view)
```

Now you can use `self.Region.bounds`, which is in the same coordinate system as the new value of `point`:

```
if CGRectContainsPoint(self.Region.bounds, point)
```

Answer (score 3):

*My first answer, even with the sketch, was messy. I've deleted it.*

So here are multiple ways to achieve what you're looking for. We'll assume that your region is an UIView.

**Solution 1**

You are retrieving the point from the **main view**, so you need to check if the **frame** of your regionView contains your point.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var regionView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:")

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
            println("[handleTap] Tap ended")

            var point = tap.locationInView(self.view)

            println("[handleTap] Tap point : x\(point.x) ; y\(point.y) (in self.view)")

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.regionView.frame, point)) {
                println("[handleTap] Tap is inside regionView")
            }

            println()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**Solution 2**

You are retrieving the point and **convert** it to the inside **regionView** coordinates system. So you need to check if the point is within **bounds** of your regionView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var regionView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:")

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
            println("[handleTap] Tap ended")

            var point = tap.locationInView(self.view)

            println("[handleTap] Tap point : x\(point.x) ; y\(point.y) (in self.view)")

            point = self.regionView.convertPoint(point, fromView: self.view)

            println("[handleTap] Tap point converted : x\(point.x) ; y\(point.y) (in self.regionView)")

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.regionView.bounds, point)) {
                println("[handleTap] Tap is inside regionView")
            }

            println()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**Solution 3**

You get the point from your **regionView** directly. So you **don't need to convert** it, however you still need to check if it's within its **bounds** like solution 2.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var regionView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        tap.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:")

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
            println("[handleTap] Tap ended")

            var point = tap.locationInView(self.regionView)

            println("[handleTap] Tap point : x\(point.x) ; y\(point.y) (in self.view)")

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.regionView.bounds, point)) {
                println("[handleTap] Tap is inside regionView")
            }

            println()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can only set your gesture recognizer on the regionView : `self.regionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)`.

Let me know if it helped !

Comment: The region is a textField, I think that's why your code doesn't work for me, when i checked it on an image it works fine.

Comment: perfect solution! I was looking for a way to dismiss controller by tapping outside an imageview and with any reason touchesBegan wasn't working on the view but this solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.state == .ended) {
        let point = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
        
        if (self.headerView.frame.contains(point)) {
            // Do something
        }
        
    }
}
```